# error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type in form validation angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having compile error while reactive validation in angular 2 which is giving

> error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any'
>   type

For

```
this.comErrors[field] = '';
const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
this.comErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
```

it is running as it should be but when im trying to run npm run build.prod, error occurs and doesnot build my project

here is my code:

```
 onValueChanged(data ?: any): void {

   if (!this.companyAddForm) { return; }
    const form = this.companyAddForm;
    for (const field in this.comErrors) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
       //errors occurs
      this.comErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get(field);
      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.comErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
}
comErrors = {
    code: "",
    name: "",
    address: "",
    subscribedOn: "",
    contactPerson: "",
    contactPhone: ""
}
validationMessages = {
  'code': {
        'required': 'Company Code is required.',
        'minlength': 'Company Code must be at least 5 characters long.',
        'maxlength': 'Company Code cannot be more than 10 characters long.'
    },
    'name': {
        'required': 'Company Name is required.',
        'minlength': 'Company Name must be at least 5 characters long.',
        'maxlength': 'Company Name cannot be more than 25 characters long.'
    },
    'address': {
        'required': 'Company Address is required.',
        'minlength': 'Company Address must be at least 5 characters long.',
        'maxlength': 'Company Address cannot be more than 25 characters long.'
    },
    'subscribedOn': {
        'required': 'subscribe date is required.'
    },
    'contactPerson': {
        'required': 'Mobile Number is required.'
    },
    'contactPhone': {
        'required': 'Mobile Number is required.'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because the compiler infers the type for `validationMessages`, and this type is not [indexable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).
The compiler needs to cast `this.validationMessages` to `any` but you are (probably) using the `--noImplicitAny` flag which causes the error.

You can do this:

```
const messages = (this.validationMessages as any)[field];
```

Or you can turn it into an indexable type:

```
type ValidationMessage = {
    required: string;
    minlength?: string;
    maxlength?: string;
}

type ValidationMessages = {
    [name: string]: ValidationMessage;
}

class A {
    validationMessages: ValidationMessages = {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To declare an object where you have no idea what the values will be, but you know that the keys will be of type string:

```
const myObject: {[key: string]: any} = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Object Destructuring you can fix with:

```
const {[field]:messages} = this.validationMessages;
```

Comment: It's just sugar syntax. Doesn't fix the "index signature" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a type for the field for which you are getting this error. If you have defined the type, somehow it is not detecting. you will need to trace it and define the type properly.

Optional: Moreover, you can also use, `io-ts` module.for runtime type checking.